# Unable to set default selection in select item

Tags: angular, dropdown, html-select

I bring data from the server and try to add a product and give it the appropriate category, I manage to add the product, but in the UI for a start I am not shown the first category
Instead, it shows me an empty option and only when I click do all the options appear.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I want from the beginning to be shown the first option, which is A.

My Code:

Components.ts:

```ts
  categories:Category[] = [];
  category!:Category;

  formNewProduct:FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,private productService:ProductService,
  private router:Router,private alertService:AlertService,public validationService:ValidationService
  ,private categoryService:CategoryService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formNewProduct = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:[''],
      description:[''],
      photoUrl:[''],
      price:[''],
      categoryId:['']
    }) 

    this.getAllCategories();

    this.category = this.categoryService.getCategory();
  }
  
  getAllCategories(){
    this.categoryService.getAllCategories().subscribe((res)=>{
      this.categories = res;
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select class="form-select" formControlName="categoryId" [(ngModel)]="category.id">
<option *ngFor="let c of categories" [value]="c.id">
{{c.name}}
</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Service:

```
  getCategory():Category{
    let categoryString = localStorage.getItem("category");
    let category = new Category;
    if(categoryString){
      category = JSON.parse(categoryString);
    }
    return category;
  }
```

Comment: I highly suggest reading up on forms on the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `patchValue` after the dropdown is fetched, then it will populate; and either perform either `reactive` or `template` driven validation not both together (not advised but allowed). Here I am populating using reactive forms.

```
categories: Category[] = [];
category!: Category;

formNewProduct: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    public validationService: ValidationService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formNewProduct = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [''],
        description: [''],
        photoUrl: [''],
        price: [''],
        categoryId: [''], 
    });
    this.getAllCategories();
}

getAllCategories() {
    this.categoryService.getAllCategories().subscribe(res => {
        this.categories = res;
        // this.category = this.categoryService.getCategory(); // not needed for now!
        this.formNewProduct.patchValue({categoryId: res[0].id}); // populate the first record in the dropdown
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-select" formControlName="categoryId">
        <option *ngFor="let c of categories" [value]="c.id">
            {{ c.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I did as you explained to me, it does allow me to add a new product, but still the main problem of displaying a depolative category is not shown to me as a start

Comment: @OpalDavid what does `getCategory` method of the service do? can I hardcode `A` to be set on load?

Comment: I added getCategory to the post, I have no use for it because I don't have setItem right now at least

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I have 2 more things I need to fix about the dropdown, do you think it's legit to open another post?

Comment: @OpalDavid Another post if the requirement is too big

Comment: I can't post it tells me to wait 90 minutes, maybe you can help me in a private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247676/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-opal-david).